# How to instantiate an object with IVdsVolumeMF2 interface?

Tags: c++, format

I'm trying to format a media use the [IVdsVolumeMF2::FormatEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa819439%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
How do I get an object that has this interface implemented?

Comment: That function is only supported on Vista and up.

Comment: @chris oh ok, thanks. I will edit tags. Although I cannot use it, I'm still wondering how to instantiate an object with this interface.

Comment: I was going to say `CoCreateInstance` until I couldn't find a specific CLSID.

Comment: Is it supposed to be something like this: `Classes\Interface\{EE2D5DED-6236-4169-931D-B9778CE03DC6}`?